# Who can you romance in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Unfortunately, the [Romance article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_3) on the Mass Effect Wikia doesn't have the options listed yet, and I'm a little paranoid about digging deeper on google for fear of running into major story spoilers (hell, I'm paranoid about those just on this site).

Who are the romance options (both same-sex and opposite-sex) that count for "Paramour" for male and female Shepards?

In addition, are there "side romances" that you can pursue in ME3? For instance, in 2, you could "romance" Kelly, Samara, or Morinth, but they did not count for the "Paramour" achievement (and one of those options ended very... uh... fatally).

Comment: I like how the wikia's description of the Morinth romance is, "You *do* know what an Ardat-Yakshi is, right?"

Comment: According to one source, anyone and anything.  [http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=309](http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=309) (NSFW)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55645/10260

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm going to keep this to names only in the interest of minimizing spoilers.

## Key

**#**: Only availiable as a continued romance if initiated in Mass Effect 2
**^**: Same Sex Romance option
**%**: Not a Squad Member
**$**: Does not count towards 'Paramour' achievement

**All listed relationships *except* for Diana Allers count for Paramour.**

## Male Shepard

**Ashley**
**Liara**
**Tali** #
**Miranda** #%
**Steve Cortez** ^%
**Kaidan** ^
**Jack** #%
**Diana Allers** %$

## Female Shepard

**Kaidan**
**Liara** ^
**Garrus** #
**Samantha Traynor** ^%
**Diana Allers** ^%$

Comment: I appreciate the spoiler-free-ness! Do all of these listed count for Paramour?

Comment: Do you have any information on Kaidan's availability for male Shepards? [His wiki article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kaidan_Alenko#Mass_Effect_3) states he is an option, but he's not listed as such in your answer.

Comment: My source (the official guide) does not indicate that Kaidan is a same sex option, but it could be inaccurate.

Comment: Are Asari technically female? >.>

Comment: Asari are mono-gendered. They *look* female, but there is no gender distinction among them. I wouldn't consider it same-sex *canonically* speaking, especially since Bioware doesn't label it as a same-sex option.

Comment: Asari don't just 'look' female. They present as female. They is female pronouns. They call their children daughters. They are monogendered, but at no time is it ever implied that they are hermaphrodites in our sense of the word either. Put another way, if Asari can be considered to have *any* gender, it's probably best marked as an **F** for fanservice.

Comment: And here you guys take my mostly-kidding side remark (Does a race with a single gender really count as any gender?) and turn it into a real discussion.  Way to ruin the joke. ;P  (FWIW I actually agree with Raven on this, but I don't see any particular reason not to consider them female for terms of this.  It's not like Bioware didn't think people would say "Oh, two chicks getting it on!")

Comment: You forgot jack (subject zero)

Comment: It's my understanding that Jack, like Thane, is not a full fledged romantic partner in ME3. While a past relationship is acknowledged, it cannot be continued.

Comment: Is it possible that this is incomplete or does male s have more options than female s?

Comment: Male Shepard has several more options than Female Shepard. Most notably, Male Shepard can continue all of his romantic options from ME 2, whereas, Femsheps that romanced Thane or Jacob, will find that their paramour is dying or has found someone else respectively. Combined with the change to Kaidan to allow him to swing both ways, and Male Shep gets 3 extra options.

Comment: Asari are, in fact, female. They procreate by parthenogenesis and are stated to be an all-female race.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz You're right, that's what I meant. It's better to say Asari lack gender than that they are exclusively female.

Comment: Are all these mutually exclusive? Or are parallel romances possible?

Comment: @EpiGrad They are mutually exclusive. Monogamy is the name of the game in Mass Effect.

Comment: @EpiGrad http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54915/can-you-romance-multiple-people

Comment: Per the answers to my other question (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55645/can-i-resume-a-romance-with-kelly-chambers) apparently this list is still incomplete.

Comment: What about the good old Thane and my favourite yeoman Kelly.

Comment: Asari may all present as female, but depending on your situation with Liara, you may meet her Asari "father" on the Citadel (remember Matriarch Benezia is her mother). You have a dialog option querying the word "father" being used for an all female parthenogenetic race, and she says she didn't"pop her out" and accuses you of being an "anthroprocentric bag of..."