# Can you romance multiple people?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 2, I remember there was a point in the game that you had to choose who to finally... close the deal with, and after you chose, the other romantic interests were not available (even though you could suggest a group effort).

Is there something similar in Mass Effect 3, where you have to choose [who to move forward with](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53695/14) and then the others reject your advances, or can I have multiple partners?

Comment: Witty comments? Anyone... anyone? Sigh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Monogamy is the name of the game in Mass Effect. In addition to being blocked out of multiple romances, those attempting to pursue a little somethin' on the side may find themselves having to do a whole lot of explaining.

Comment: Not entirely, in ME2 there was the option Jack gave you to just have a one time fling and then blows you off, still allowing for other options to flourish if so desired, but then you might also be at risk of changed dialog from 2 to 3, which I can't substantiate