# Can I be both straight and gay?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cortez thinks I'm gay, will it affect my chances to date women?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/cortez-thinks-im-gay-will-it-affect-my-chances-to-date-women)

From reading through the [Romance Mass Effect wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_3) and [LessPop_MoreFizz's succinct answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53601/19997), it's clear that I can pursue either sex as romantic options.

However, from what I've read of [other people's experiences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56142/19997) in this area, once the crew figures out your sexual orientation, the opposite gender tends to keep their distance. For instance, if I'm playing a female Shepard and choose to pursue Traynor, Kaidan will pick up on this and take a few steps back, romantically-speaking.

So all of that leads to my question. **Is it possible to have relationships of both a homosexual and heterosexual nature in the same playthrough?** That is, can I hook up with a guy at some point and then, down the line, hook up with a female? Is it possible to have two such relationships at the same time even?

**And where do the asari fit in the gay/straight spectrum?** I understand they're generally considered an all female species. Does romanticizing Liara count as a gay, straight, or something else entirely?

Comment: Additionally, see: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54915/can-you-romance-multiple-people

Comment: @RavenDreamer The marked dupe doesn't address whether you can actually have relationships with characters of both sexes.  I'm unclear on whether the one in your comment says that it's never possible to have 2 relationships, or just not 2 at the same time.

Comment: @MatthewRead it says the former; the game won't let you have more than 1 relationship, ever.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It says "Monogamy is the name of the game"; serial monogamy is still monogamy.  If you know it's one and one only then I trust you, but if I were johnjon I would have wanted this explained.

Comment: @MatthewRead The very next sentence says "In addition to being blocked out of multiple romances..."

Comment: I thought "at the same time" was implied in that sentence, but I see your point.