# How can you romance Diana Allers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In this [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53601/who-can-you-romance-in-mass-effect-3) I saw you can romance Diana Allers.

How can you do it? I have done some missions but can't speak with her, and there aren't any options besides getting her out of the Normandy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each third of the game - Priority Tuchanka, Rannoch, or Thessia, Diana Allers (if aboard) will send an email requesting an interview. Shep can go up to his cabin and use the intercom to send her up for an interview.

After she asks her questions, she'll turn off the camera and make some small talk - after the first interview, you are given the option to flirt with her or turn her down. If you turn her down, she never mentions it again, but if you flirt with her, you can then flirt after the other two interviews and eventually she will become a love interest.

Comment: Does this work with a FemShepard too?

Comment: @JuanManuel Not sure. I'd check LessPop's "Who can I romance" answer.

Comment: According to his answer (which I just checked thanks to you) you can! :)

Comment: I wonder if her voice acting is as bad during the "romance" scene as it is in the rest of the game...

Comment: Never gets any better; she gives a little speech near the end about her home and its delivered in flat, emotionless monotone.

Comment: @Vaishali http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53695/16849