# Jacob romance in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

[Since you can't pursue a relationship with Jacob](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53601/21724), what happens in Mass Effect 3 if you romanced him in Mass effect 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He marries Brynn no matter what. You can try to convince him to give Shpeard a kiss, but he won't do it.